# Does Batesian mimicry rely on constant reinforcement?

Tags: adaptation, lepidoptera

If the species being mimicked, the monarch butterfly, for instance, were to become extinct, would the species mimicking it loose all of the benefit gained by their Batesian mimicry immediately?

I realize that the Monarch may be a poor example as it is a Müllerian mimic with the Viceroy butterfly, however their ranges do not overlap everywhere. Would the extinction of the monarch reduce the ranges of Batesian mimics to that of the Viceroy?